# Disabling TLS 1.1 in node.js?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ssl, openssl, ubuntu-12.04

I am currently experiencing a known problem with OpenSSL on Ubuntu 12.04. This problem is already fixed in Debian and I'm expecting it to be fixed soon in Ubuntu too. However, in the mean time I would need a workaround.

So is it possible to disable TLS1 in Node and have something equivalent to `tls1` switch:

```
openssl s_client -tls1 -connect evernote.com:443
```

Here is a simple Node.js script to replicate the problem (on Ubuntu 12.04 w/ OpenSSL 1.0.1)

```
var https = require('https');
https.get({
    host: 'www.evernote.com',
    path: '/',
    port: 443
  }, function (res) {
    console.log('Success!');
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https.request) and the sources ([1](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/3415427dbfbd590bbee3d777ffc73dde3c67790d/src/node_crypto.cc#L185), [2](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/3415427dbfbd590bbee3d777ffc73dde3c67790d/lib/crypto.js#L70)), it should be possible to pass an options object to `request` that contains something like

```
options = { secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method' }
```

in order to use TLSv1 (and just that) for this particular connection.

The default is to use OpenSSL's SSLv23_method, which means to use the highest TLS/SSL version that is possibly understood by both parties.

Although possible in OpenSSL itself, it is not possible to blacklist a particular TLS version (as in "use the highest version possible, but never this one") in node.js as far as I can see, the necessary flags to do so are not exported in node.js itself.

Comment: AWESOME reverse-engineering! Too bad it seems I want be able to do what I would need to :( Are you sure it works like that? I tried using various values (`SSLv2_method`, `TLSv1_method`) for `secureProtocol`, but seems like I get the same error regardless (`Error: socket hang up`, `at SecurePair.error (tls.js:802:15)`) Thanks a million so far!

Comment: I didn't get it to work, but I think this is basically as far as we can go with the information available. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't have the time to investigate further. If I manage to find out what could have gone wrong, I'll put it in a comment here!

Comment: jsalonen, have you figure it out?  By the way, where should the options go to?   in HttpsOptions?  or where?

Comment: @jsalonen They go in a new https.Agent.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a bug where I couldn't connect to livefilestore.com over ssl via node. Here is what fixed it:

```
var https = require('https');

var HTTPS_AGENT = new https.Agent({
 secureProtocol: 'SSLv3_method'     // default is SSLv23_method
});

var req_opts = {...};

req_opts.agent = HTTPS_AGENT;

https.request(req_opts, function(res) { ... });
```

Interestingly, I was able to reproduce the error in curl with more recent versions of libopenssl, but my older boxes didn't reproduce the issue. I was able to reproduce on Ubuntu and Gentoo. In experimenting with curl, using the -2 always breaks (differently though, doesn't hang, just reports unsupported) and -3 never reproduced the problem. I don't know if that is related at all. Without specifying -3 it tries and fails to do an SSLv3 handshake. Strange.